# Can I get Diamox over the counter in Nairobi?

Tags: kilimanjaro, nairobi

I'm planning on hiking Kilimanjaro and will be in Nairobi for a while before that. Will I be able to buy the altitude sickness medication diamox there or in Kilimanjaro National Park? Can I get it over the counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just walked in to a pharmacy in Nairobi (at Yaya Center, to be exact) to ask for Diamox. They *do* have it over the counter. No prescription is necessary. It is 50 Ksh per tablet (a little over USD 0.50).

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot get it OTC. I contacted Thomson Treks and they said that it was prescription only and could not be bought OTC. They sounds reasonable considering it is prescription only in the U.S. If you have a prescription about it, altitude sickness problems, that is another thing.

I am contacted them about alternative altitude sickness medications, and they said that you should just bring them from the U.S.

Comment: Nice. If they respond to your email, please do add it in! :D

Comment: @MarkMayo I just realized you were the one hosting the answer-a-thin thingie. :)

Comment: @MarkMayo Updated.